# Image background after conversion of Qt Designer to Python

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

im working on a desktop application (im a begginer) using Qt designer and Python and i need some help. When i add some pictures (images, background images) on Qt, i don't find them on my window on python after conversion.

Window on Qt designer

[image: Window on Qt designer]

Window on python

[image: Window on python].

And here is the python code.

```py
import sys

from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication, QWidget, QStackedWidget


class WelcomeScreen(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(WelcomeScreen, self).__init__()
        loadUi("Welcome.ui",self)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
welcome = WelcomeScreen()
widget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
widget.addWidget(welcome)
widget.setFixedWidth(932)
widget.setFixedHeight(562)
widget.show()
try:
    sys.exit(app.exec())
except:
    print("Exiting")
```

Comment: this should help : [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TAJwrIO_ctI)

Comment: My guess is that the "translated" code produced by calling `loadUi("Welcome.ui",self)` does not end up with the proper file path to the background image (relative to the folder where your script executes). This might be tricky to debug - one idea is to convert the `.ui` file to a `.py` file and double-check how it attempts to load the image. This lack of transparency is one of the reasons why I prefer writing GUI code directly instead of relying on QtDesigner.

Comment: @HAMZAAZOUGA image directly added as files are not embedded in the UI, and should always be relative to the working directory, so you probably added the images from another path that doesn't match the one you're using; you could also use [resource files in Designer](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-resources.html), but in that case you also need to compile the `qrc` file with pyrcc. Be aware that you're probably following a YouTube tutorial ("Code First with Hala") that is known to suggest *a lot* of **terrible** practices, and I strongly urge you to dismiss it and look for other resources.

Comment: @LSeu Yes thank you the video helped.

Comment: @musicamante Yes i was following ("Code First with hala") and as you said i will look for other resources. Thank's mate.